# How to put two different elements inside one div with appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I've looked up others questions which got nearly the same topic but sadly haven't found a working solution for myself.
I want to put two `a` Elements inside of one created `div` Element with `appendChild` but I can't just append them both together, cause it tells me that it only expects one argument.

```
let view = this.view as Nullable<HTMLElement>;
let link_1 = document.createElement('a');
let link_2 = document.createElement('a');
let link_container = document.createElement('div');
link_container.setAttribute('style', 'display: flex;');

const cont = link_container.appendChild(link_1, link_2);

view?.appendChild(cont);
```

I would really appreciate a working solution.

Comment: Just call appendChild once for each ( = 2 times)

Comment: Firstly you have a typo. view.appendChild(cont); And secondly yes, appendChild() only accept one argument so you simply call it twice (no need to bind it to a variable neither).

Answer (score 3):

Use just append[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), not appendChild

```
let view = this.view as Nullable<HTMLElement>;
let link_1 = document.createElement('a');
let link_2 = document.createElement('a');
let link_container = document.createElement('div');
link_container.setAttribute('style', 'display: flex;');

const cont = link_container.append(link_1, link_2);
```

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Nope, in the documentation you can see the diferences betwenn append and appendChild: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: From the documentation you linked: "Element.append() has no return value"

Answer (score 0):

Create array to store the no of links variable that you want to create and the create for loop to append a child element on single div.

This will be a dynamic approach you can append multiple child elements in single parent.

like this:

```
let view = this.view as Nullable<HTMLElement>;
let link_1 = document.createElement('a');
let link_2 = document.createElement('a');
let link_container = document.createElement('div');
link_container.setAttribute('style', 'display: flex;');

const links = [link_1, link_2];

links.forEach(link => {
   link_container.appendChild(link);
})

view?.appendChild(cont);
```